# ASP.NET Core 6 AuthorizeView not working with arrays

Tags: asp.net, blazor-webassembly

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 WASM project that working on currently. The solution contains three projects server, client, and shared. I have implemented my own authentication and authorization, not using the Duende Identity.

I have most everything working I think at this point. I am able to log in and out, `AuthorizeView` tag works until I specify roles or policies required for that view. I am trying to `AuthorizeView` tag and the Authorize attribute, and they both fail.

I am focusing on the `AuthorizeView` tag, at the moment. I leaning to maybe the roles of the user is in a string array, is causing problems?   I see that there is a way with Duende to handle arrays with the `AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory` function, don't see any equivalent functional without Duende. I know the roles are being populate because, they can be listed out within `AuthorizeView`.

So, I am pretty confident everything is working properly up to the point of `AuthorizeView` tag. Tried changing the ordering of the `AddAuthorizationCore` and `CustomAuthStateProvider` lines in the `Program.cs` `Main` function.

Any suggestions or thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

The output of my test page is

```
TestPage
<b>Logged in.</b>
User: admin
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name -> admin
Email -> not set
useruuid -> 80076237FEB8394EA9BB4CC61E5A165A
expires -> 5/31/2023 7:20:26 PM
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role -> ["SysAdmin","User","IT","DEV"]
exp -> 1685560826
iss -> https://localhost:7143
aud -> https://localhost:7143
Please signed in.    <b> This should be valid and displaying a different message in my mind, since there is a policy defined for this user</b>
Please signed in.
```

The code client side

```
public class Program {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.Services.AddOptions();
    
        //  Remove non authorization / authentication lines
 
            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(config => {
                config.AddPolicy(UserRoles.SysAdmin, Policies.SysAdminPolicy());
                config.AddPolicy(UserRoles.User, Policies.UserPolicy());
                config.AddPolicy(UserRoles.IT, Policies.ITPolicy());      
                config.AddPolicy(UserRoles.Dev, Policies.DevPolicy());        
            });     

            builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthStateProvider>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthStateProvider>());

            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

            //  removed non authorization / authentication lines 

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }    
}
```

TestPage.razor

```
@*@attribute [Authorize(Policy = UserRoles.Dev)] *@

<h3>TestPage</h3>

<AuthorizeView Context="innerContext">
    <Authorized>
        <p>Logged in.</p>
        <p>User: @innerContext.User.Identity.Name</p>
        @foreach(Claim c in innerContext.User.Claims) {
            <p>@c.Type -> @c.Value</p>          
        }
        <hr/>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>Please signed in.</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


<AuthorizeView Policy="@UserRoles.Dev">
    <Authorized>   
        Authorized for the Dev Policy
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>Please signed in.</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

<AuthorizeView Roles="@UserRoles.Dev">
    <Authorized>   
    Authorized for the Dev Role
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>Please signed in.</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

CustomAuthStateProvider Class

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider {
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage; 
    private readonly HttpClient _http;

    public static bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    public static bool IsAuthenticating { get; set; } 

    public CustomAuthStateProvider(ILocalStorageService localStorage, HttpClient http) {
        _localStorage = localStorage; 
        _http = http;  
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() {
        try {
            var savedToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>(AuthToken.TokenIdentifier);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken)) {
                return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
            }

            _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), Globals.ClaimTypeName)));
        } catch {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity())); 
        }

 //   ClaimsIdentity identity;

        //if (IsAuthenticating) {
        //  return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        //} else if (IsAuthenticated) {
 //     var savedToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>(AuthToken.TokenIdentifier);
 //     identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken) , Globals.ClaimTypeName);
        //} else {
        //  identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        //}

        //return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity)));
    }

    #region ::  Notifications        ::
    public void NotifyAuthState() {
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }

    public void NotifyAuthStateLogon() {
        IsLoggedIn = true;
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
        KeepSession();
    }

    public async Task NotifyAuthStateLogout() {
        IsLoggedIn = false;
        IsAuthenticated = false;
        IsAuthenticating = false;

        AuthToken.TokenValue = "";
        await _localStorage.SetItemAsync(AuthToken.TokenIdentifier, "");
        _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Code from my shared library

```
public static class UserRoles {
        public const string SysAdmin = "SysAdmin";
        public const string User = "User";
        public const string IT = "IT"; 
        public const string Dev = "DEV";
}

public static class Policies {
        public static AuthorizationPolicy SysAdminPolicy() {
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                   .RequireRole(UserRoles.SysAdmin)
                                                   .Build();
        }

        public static AuthorizationPolicy UserPolicy() {
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                   .RequireRole(UserRoles.User)
                                                   .Build();
        }

        public static AuthorizationPolicy ITPolicy() {
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                   .RequireRole(UserRoles.IT)
                                                   .Build();
        }       

        public static AuthorizationPolicy DevPolicy() {
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                   .RequireRole(UserRoles.Dev)
                                                   .Build();
        }    
}
```